# Ubuntu MATE: How to enter and exit full screen view using key combination in virt-manager?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-mate, fullscreen, virt-manager

Is there a key combination to enter and exit fullscreen view in virt-manager, while a virtual machine is running, and its window open?

Obviously I can enter or exit using mouse:

To enter: Click `View` > `Fullscreen`

To exit: Hover mouse at the top-center, and click `Leave fullscreen` icon.

I have tried key combinations from this AskUbuntu thread: [How do I unmaximize full screen view in virt-manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43861/how-do-i-unmaximize-full-screen-view-in-virt-manager) but they are not working in Ubuntu MATE 21.04. Many thanks.

OS: Ubuntu MATE 21.04

virt-manager: 1:3.2.0-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab keyboard back by <kbd>Ctrl_L</kbd>+<kbd>Alt_L</kbd> and then use graphical widget on top

[image: leave fullscreen]

to switch to windowed mode.

Also see https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/issues/91 . It is bug (and bad documentation) of `virt-manager`, not in Ubuntu or Ubuntu MATE itself.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Let's see if the developers add proper key combination like VMware or VirtualBox, if ever.